# Why my Ubuntu 16.04 does't work with lower than 2Mbps internet connections?

Tags: networking, ubuntu, wireless-networking, internet, connection

I don't know why my Ubuntu 16.04 doesn't work with my home's internet connection(It's speed is 512Kbps(64KBps download speed)). When I share my phone's 4G connection, or I took my laptop to my office with 2Mbps connection, it works fine, but at home it doesn't work! It only works for 30secconds and I must disconnect/reconnect to open a new site, and I should disconnect/reconnect again if I want to open another new site! I re-installed the Ubuntu but couldn't solve my problem!

What causes this terrible problem and is there anyway to solve it?

Comment: I ran Ubuntu16.04 with a slow mobile phone connection (Edge) and it worked OK... If the home modem is shared with other devices, do they see the interruption too when it occurs on your PC?

Comment: No, the problem is only with Ubuntu, cause I have windows 10 in this laptop and it works fine, also other connected devices to this network work well!